# Remove Leading Commas via Coalasce and NULLIF?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

```
UPDATE PropertyInformationDump
   SET RegistryAdd = COALESCE(NULLIF(b.OCAREOF, ''), b.OCAREOF + ', ','') +
       COALESCE(NULLIF(b.O1STADD, ''), b.O1STADD + ', ','') + 
       COALESCE(NULLIF(b.O2NDADD, '') + b.O2NDADD + ', ','') + 
       COALESCE(b.OSTNAME + ', ','') + COALESCE(b.OCITYST + '  ','') +  
       COALESCE(NULLIF(b.OZIP, ''), b.OZIP,'')
  FROM dbo.vw_BRT b
 WHERE BRTNumber = b.PARCEL
GO
```

Looking to remove the commas that are in the front of these combined strings.  Here is an example of what is happening:

```
, , 1350 SUSQUEHANNA AVE, PHILADELPHIA PA  19125
MICHAEL J CARLONE, 10050 ROOSEVELT BLVD, PHILADELPHIA PA  191163924
```

Need it to always look like:

```
1350 SUSQUEHANNA AVE, PHILADELPHIA PA  19125
```

or just how the one with the OCAREOF filled:

```
MICHAEL J CARLONE, 10050 ROOSEVELT BLVD, PHILADELPHIA PA  191163924
```

I need to get rid of those commas if the field is empty or null.  Apparently I am doing this incorrectly!

Comment: what DBMS are you on? I don't think you need the COALESCE in your syntax, the NULLIF and adding a comma should take care of it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using SQL Server 2005 the following should work

```
UPDATE PropertyInformationDump
SET RegistryAdd = 
    CASE WHEN Len(b.OCAREOF) > 0 THEN b.OCAREOF + ',' ELSE '' END + 
    CASE WHEN Len(b.O1STADD) > 0 THEN b.O1STADD + ',' ELSE '' END  + 
    CASE WHEN Len(b.O2NDADD) > 0 THEN b.O2NDADD + ',' ELSE '' END  + 
    CASE WHEN Len(b.OSTNAME ) > 0 THEN b.OSTNAME + ',' ELSE '' END  + 
    CASE WHEN Len(b.OCITYST) > 0 THEN b.OCITYST+ ',' ELSE '' END  + 
    CASE WHEN Len(b.OZIP) > 0 THEN b.OZIP+ ',' ELSE '' END 
FROM dbo.vw_BRT b
WHERE BRTNumber = b.PARCEL
```

If the fields are either empty of have data then you can ignore using `isNull()`

Comment: Right but sometimes the field is empty so IsNull will still cause the same problem. I get ,,,1350 SUSQUEHANNA AVE,PHILADELPHIA PA,19125, with that code.

Comment: @korrowan i've updated to only add a comma when the field is not empty.

Comment: Okay cool this works.  made some adjustments to get the exact string I need but it works well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(b.OCAREOF + ', ', ''),'')
```

**UPDATE**

If your fields are not nullable use this:

```
CASE WHEN LEN(b.OCAREOF) = 0 THEN '' ELSE b.OCAREOF + ', ' END +
....
```

Comment: If I use that I get: , , , 1350 SUSQUEHANNA AVE, PHILADELPHIA PA  19125

Comment: @korrowan Does your fields empty ('') or NULL?

Comment: I am sure that is what I get when using that.  I will try to upload some data shortly.